# ESLint rule for preventing exports that match a pattern

Tags: eslint, typescript-eslint

I'm interested in a rule that will only allow exports that match a certain pattern.
For example, I want a rule that will allow only exports ending in Api:
`export {MyClass} from './myClass.ts'` should fail. But, `export {MyClassApi} from './myClass.ts'` should pass.